# What the reason for enclosing code in a "using" in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
        try
        {
            using (var context = new DataContext())
            {
                if (!context.Database.Exists())
                {
                    // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                }
            }


            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("xxx", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            var sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("SqlScript.sql");
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
        }
```

Can someone explain what the purpose of the "using" is ?

Comment: Outside using your variables are getting disposed. Meaning you do not need to explicitly close FileStreams, Database Connections, etc.

Comment: What have you not understood in the [**manual**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for a proper disposal pattern.

It is equivalent to

```
DataContext context = new DataContext();
try
{
   // using context here
}
finally
{
  if(context != null)
    ((IDisposable)context).Dispose();
}
```

This is described in the MSDN article for [`using Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Using `using` in this way ensures proper disposable and reduces chances of programmer mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

`using` automatically dispose the object after it has been used. You don't need to manually call `.Dispose()`.

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    // other codes
}  
// at this point the context is already disposed
```

is the same as

```
var context = new DataContext()
// other codes
context.Dispose()    // manually calling Dispose()
// at this point the context is already disposed
```

- [**using** Statement <sup>MSDN Manual</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: No _exactly_ the same.

Comment: Except that there still is a difference with exception handling. So the 2 blocks arent really 'equal'. See odeds answer.

Answer (score 0):

`using` statement ensures that `Dispose` is called at the end of using block. Your code is equivalent to:

```
var context = new DataContext();

try
{ 
   if (!context.Database.Exists())
   {
       ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
   }
}
finally
{
    if (context != null)
        context.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the `"using"` statement is to ensure that the object is always `disposed` correctly, and it doesn't require explicit code to ensure that this happens.

The `using` statement simplifies the code that you have to write to create and then finally clean up the object.

```
using (MyResource myRes = new MyResource())
{
    myRes.DoSomething();
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
MyResource myRes= new MyResource();
try
{
    myRes.DoSomething();
}
finally
{
    // Check for a null resource.
    if (myRes!= null)
        // Call the object's Dispose method.
        ((IDisposable)myRes).Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `using` is used for objects which implement the `IDisposable` Interface - they are containing unmanaged resources which would not be cleared, if the object was collected by the garbage collector.
When using `using` you limit the scope of the object to the curly braces and when the `using`-Statement is left, all unmanaged resources are disposed of.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article here.